# Cannot change widget config from a method (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I have a class where I create a Label on the **init** method:

```python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        label1 = tk.Label(master, text="Select file...")
        label1.pack()
```

Then with a button I call a method to choose a file and change the label text to filename path.

```python
    def files(self):
        filename = askopenfilename()
        self.label1.config(text=filename)
```

The problem is that when I choose the file, the app gets closed without errors, so I don't know what's going on.

Outside the class I have:

```python
root = tk.Tk()
app_gui = app(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to set `self.label1` in `__init__` method.  Right now it's a local name `label1`, not an instance attribute `self.label1`.

Comment: Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/) and [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: @stovfl Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, there are two problems. The first is that you're creating two instances of `tk.Tk`. You should never do that.

The second is that you aren't creating `self.label1` so any attempt to modify it will fail.

The solution is to first remove `tk.Tk` as a superclass for `app`. The second is to properly define `self.label1`

```
class app():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.label1 = tk.Label(...)
        ...
```

---

On a side note, you should seriously consider following the naming conventions of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and name your main class `App`. PEP8 is nearly universal in the python world, and deviating from it makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Thanks. I am quite new to python, and even more to OOP.